# What is the difference between an object's set of attributes and its namespace?

Tags: python, oop, object, namespaces

Set of attributes of an object form a namespace. To access that attribute, you must specify the namespace: `obj.attr`. Does this mean that attributes of objects are just names defined within a specific namespace (object name)? Or is there a distinction? For instance, references to names in modules are attribute references: in the expression `modname.function`, `modname` is a module object and `funcname` is an attribute of it, ([see: 9.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)) but when you define a function like the following, there's a clear distinction between the namespace of the function and the attributes of it:

```
>>> def aFunction():
    x=1
    y=2
    z=3
    #three names have been defined in the local namespace,
    #but aren't considered to be attributes of aFunction from what I understand.
```

I'm really confused. Can somebody please elaborate on this and explain the difference between an object's namespace and its attributes?

Comment: The problem here is your ill-defined notion of "an object's namespace". Functions have an attribute namespace, and each call to a function has a local variable namespace. These are different namespaces, but by thinking in terms of "an object's namespace", you end up mixing up the concepts. There's more than one way a namespace can be conceptually associated with an object.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to quote the documentation:

> A namespace is a **mapping from names to objects**. Most namespaces are currently implemented as Python dictionaries, but that’s normally not noticeable in any way (except for performance), and it may change in the future. Examples of namespaces are: the set of built-in names (containing functions such as `abs()`, and built-in exception names); the **global** names in a module; and the **local** names in a function invocation. **In a sense the set of attributes of an object also form a namespace.** The important thing to know about namespaces is that there is **absolutely no relation** between names in different namespaces;

So, as @user2357112 supports Monica said in the comments:

> There's more than one way a namespace can be conceptually associated with an object.

Kent Johnson also [talked](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-January/059823.html) about it well:

> Another way to think of it is, a namespace is a place where names are
> looked up. When you use a bare name (not an attribute), it is looked up
> in the local namespace, then the global namespace, then the built-in
> namespace. For example:
>
> ```
> y = 2  # Defines y in the global (module) namespace
>
> def f():
>   x = 1 # Defines x in the local (function) namespace
>
>   # This looks up x, finds it in the local namespace
>   # looks up abs, finds it in the built-in namespace
>   print abs(x)
>
>   # This looks up y, finds it in the global namespace
>   print y
> ```
>
> Note that none of the above namespaces have a related `__dict__`
> attribute, the namespace mappings are not stored that way.
>
> Objects also define a sort of namespace, where attributes are defined
> and looked up. The dict containing the namespace of an object is itself
> stored as an attribute of the object, called `__dict__`. So `__dict__` is an
> implementation detail of the way object attributes are stored.
>
> As a beginner, it is important to understand the way bare names are
> looked up (`local`, `global`, `built-in` namespace) and a bit about the way
> attributes work. You don't have to be concerned with the implementation
> details such as `__dict__`.

You can explore different namespaces using the [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function, which:

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

```
def foo(a):
    if a == 3:
        b = 1
    else:
        c = 1
    print("Local function namespace: ", dir())


a = 2
b = 3
foo.custom_attr = "some attr"
foo(a)
foo(b)
print("Global namespace: ", dir())
print("foo object namespace via dir: ", dir(foo))
print("foo object namespace via __dict__: ", foo.__dict__)
print("Built-in namespace: ", dir(__builtins__))
```

Output:

```
Local function namespace:  ['a', 'c']
Local function namespace:  ['a', 'b']
Global namespace:  ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'a', 'b', 'foo']
foo object namespace via dir:  ['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'custom_attr']
foo object namespace via __dict__:  {'custom_attr': 'some attr'}
Built-in namespace:  ['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', [...]
```